# Задача: фильтрация массива чисел

Tags: javascript

Напиши функцию filterArray(numbers, value), которая принимает массив чисел (параметр numbers) и возвращает новый массив, в котором будут только те элементы массива numbers, которые больше чем значение параметра value (число).

при этом есть условие - В цикле for использовался метод push

```
function filterArray(numbers, value) {
const newArray = [];
for(let i = 0; i > value; i++)
newArray.push(numbers[i])
return newArray;
}
```

консоль выводит пустой массив, не понимаю почему

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых не `i > value`, а `i < value`

Во-вторых не `i < value` а `i < numbers.length`

В-третьих внутри цикла не хватает условия. Как раз того, что у вас стоИт в задаче (те элементы массива numbers, которые больше чем значение параметра value)

Comment: Алексей не судите строго за этот индийский код, так как только начинаю учится, но у меня что то не выходит 
function filterArray(numbers, value) {
const newArray = [];
for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
if(i > numbers){
numbers.push(i)
}
return newArray;
}
console.log(filterArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3))

Comment: как вы думаете что значит `i > numbers` ?  и где конкретно в этом условии соблюдается проверка на то. чтобы **VALUE** был больше элемента массива?

Answer (score 0):

```
function filterArray(numbers, value) {
    const newArray = [];
    
    for(let i = 0; numbers.length > i; i++){
       
        if (numbers[i]>value){
            newArray.push(numbers[i])
        }
      
    }
        console.log(newArray);
        // [5, 10, 15, 21, 4]
        return newArray
    }

filterArray([1,2,5,10,15,21,4],2);
```

Comment: спасибо, разобрался